# How to pipe JSON output of curl to query a JSON value using python

Tags: python, json, bash, curl, gitlab-ci

I am writing a bash script where the curl command returns a JSON array of objects and then I need to filter the required values out of those objects. So I need to iterate through the objects to check then and parse them and finally get the result.

But inside my bash script if I do something like,

```
for i in 1 2 3 4
    do
        curl -XGET 'https://gitlab.com/user/api/v4/projects/1/pipelines/1/jobs' | python -c 'import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)[$i]["stage"])'
    done
```

I get the following error:

```
File "<string>", line 1
    import sys, json; print($i)
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
100  3016  100  3016    0     0  18748      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 19210
(23) Failed writing body
```

Everything Ok if I remove the python part after the pipe, but why can't I use python in combination with curl ? what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: You should be able to trivially remove curl, bash, JSON and Gitlab from all of this to produce a minimal and complete example. That said, check out `jq`, which is a processor for JSON.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt...I dont want the build systems to install another dependency so I dropped that idea. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, what's the goal of this loop? Is there a reason you want to run `curl` four times, rather than just running it once and reading the results into four elements of a shell array?

Comment: As dependencies go, `jq` is pretty lightweight; it's a single statically linked executable. It's hard to justify using anything else over `curl '...' | jq -r '.[1:5][]|.stage'` (no shell loop needed, assuming you don't really need to run `curl` 4 times).

Comment: *nod* -- and if you want to, say, treat the individual results in shell separately, that's easily done with `mapfile -t stages < <(curl ... | jq ...)` to put them into `${stages[0]}`, `${stages[1]}`, etc. Same is possible with Python just as much as jq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bash` (and other shells), variables are not expanded when put inside single quotes.

Better approach than my original (as @chepner pointed out), pass the shell variable as command line argument to `python` command itself:

```
curl ... | python -c \
   'import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)[sys.argv[1]]["stage"])' "$i"
```

**Original:**

You can get around by using double quotes like:

```
curl ... | python -c \
            'import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)['"$i"']["stage"])'
```

i.e. terminating the single quote just before variable reference, and continuing afterwards.

Comment: I don't recommend building the Python command dynamically like this; rather, pass `$i` via a command-line argument. `python -c 'import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)[sys.argv[1]]["stage"])' "$i"`.

Comment: @chepner Agreed. Edited.

Comment: BTW, I wonder if the OP would be better served by Python code that prints the results for all four stages one line at a time, and reads that into a bash array in a single pass rather than needing to run four identical `curl` commands to extract separate elements from the same array.

Comment: (Depending on the details of the data structure, it might need to be `int(sys.argv[1])` rather than leaving that as a string; OP didn't really provide enough detail to say).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes. Given OP has accepted the answer, i guess we can assume they are take it from here (probably) :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy...I would love to hear about the solution you mentioned in your first comment. Regarding storing the stages into an array in single go. Can you please let me know what details you need, I can provide. I would love to see the solution.